# How to exclude empty cells from array

Tags: excel, vba

My code:

```
   For wiersze = 3 To p2
        For kolumny = p3 To p4
            a1 = Val(wrks1.Cells(wiersze, kolumny))
            a2 = Val(wrks.Cells(wiersze, kolumny))
            Set rng = wrks1.Cells(wiersze, kolumny)
            rng.ClearComments

            rng.Comment.Text Text:="Zaoszczedzono: " & a1 - a2
        Next
    Next
```

I don't know how can I exclude empty cells from array to don't write comments on this cells. 
When I have 1 cell selected I can use this code:

```
Set P1 = Sheet1.Range("A10")
If Not IsEmpty(P1.Value) Then 
P1.addComment
```

But I don't have any idea how to rebuild my code and apply 2nd code to array.

Comment: Maybe rather than keep asking for help, go through some tutorials? This is your 5th post about the exact same macro, and What you're trying to do requires minimum effort. Don't blindly copy code from the Internet and expect SO community to re-write it for you. Try to learn to code yourself!

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if a cell is empty, there is the `=ISBLANK()` worksheet function.